# Rails: Couldn't find a file for 'twitter/bootstrap'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, assets

I'm using twitter bootstrap in my Rails application. It works well in development mode but does not in production. Here is the Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '1.9.3'
gem 'rails' 
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'haml-rails'
gem 'devise'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby'
gem 'curb'
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'pg'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails'
  gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
  gem 'uglifier'
end
```

When I run it as rails s -e production it gives me the error of

```
ActionView::Template::Error (couldn't find file 'twitter/bootstrap'
  (in /home/alex/Documents/ruby_projects/p1/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:15)):
```

**Application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

**production.rb**

```
config.serve_static_assets = false

# Compress JavaScripts and CSS
config.assets.compress = true

# Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
config.assets.compile = true

# Generate digests for assets URLs
config.assets.digest = true
```

Somebody suggested me to remove `gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'` which I cannot do because I use it or move it outside of group assets which didn't help me either: the application well except the fact that twitter bootstrap files (js and css) weren't loaded at all.

How do I fix it?

**UPDATE**:

If I use use `//= require bootstrap` instead of `//= require twitter/bootstrap` then it gives me `cannot load such file -- less (in home/alex/Documents/ruby_projects/pr1/app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_and_overr‌​ides.css.less)` despite the fact that the file exists.

And if I rename `css.less to css`, then I get the next error `couldn't find file 'bootstrap_and_overrides' (in /home/alex/Documents/ruby_projects/pr1/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:15)‌​`

Comment: I was under the impression that this line: `*= require twitter/bootstrap` goes into the `application.css` not `application.js`. Additionally, for more recent version of the gem it should be: `*= require bootstrap_and_overrides` within the `.css` after you're done running: `rails g bootstrap:install`. Source: https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/wiki/Upgrading-Guide

Comment: @Alan Dert : I have same issue now , did you solved your issue?

Comment: @suresh.g did you try restarting the rails server?

Comment: @AlexanderSuraphel : I fixed this issue and answer posted here... Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I solved this issue by using following steps:

1. Move **twitter-bootstrap-rails** gem from outside of :assets in gemfile
2. Update **twitter-bootstrap-rails** gem version **2.2.6** or 
   just paste below line in your gemfile.

   **gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', :git => 'git://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git'**

**(or)**

if twitter-bootstrap-rails 2.2.6 is not working then 
Use **twitter-bootstrap-rails gem latest version**.

Answer (score 13):

Restarting the server worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

Just use `//= require bootstrap` instead of `//= require twitter/bootstrap`.

Comment: it gives me `cannot load such file -- less (in home/alex/Documents/ruby_projects/pr1/app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less)` despite the fact that the file exists.

Comment: and if I rename cs.less to cs, then I get the next error `couldn't find file 'bootstrap_and_overrides'
  (in /home/alex/Documents/ruby_projects/pr1/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:15)`

Comment: It worked for me, but I'm using bootstrap-sass gem instead the mentioned twitter-bootstrap-rails gem.

Answer (score 2):

Requiring Bootstrap LESS (bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less) in your application.css is meaningless here, because the pipeline comes already with "require_tree ." which automatically includes everything inside the folders of the asset pipeline.

so, I suggest you to do some changes in your Gemfile.

Move the following gems from outside of :assets in Gemfile.

do this

```
gem "therubyracer"
gem "less-rails"
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"
```

instead of this

```
group :assets do
  gem "therubyracer"
  gem "less-rails"
  gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Follwing steps worked for me:

1. Move twitter-bootstrap-rails gem from outside of :assets in gemfile
2. replace the twitter bootstrap gem by this (gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails", '~> 2.2.6') in gemfile
3. bundle update
4. restart server and test